# Rewrite rules stop working when document root changes

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two copies of a folder in separate locations. They contain the exact same .htaccess file. Both .htaccess files have the same permissions and owners.

```
/home/sites/site/public_html/
/var/www/html/site/
```

I had a VirtualHost whose DocumentRoot used to point to `/home/sites` but I changed it to `/var/www` and restarted Apache.

Now my htaccess rules no longer work. For example, `/story/id` should rewrite to `/index.php?id=$id`. If I go to `/index.php?id=$id` in my browser, the page loads as it should, but if I go to `/story/id` I get a 404 error.

If I change DocumentRoot back to the old root, the links start working again.

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: what does your htaccess file/s look like?

Comment: I figured it out but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was in the main httpd.conf file. AllowOverride was set to none for `/var/www/html`, which didn't matter before because the web folder was in `/home/`. Once we set that to `All`, the rewrite rules started working again.